# Generate Automated Google Analytics Excel Reports

Tags: excel, google-analytics

I want to be able to create reports in Excel which read data from Google Analytics
How do I go about doing this? I find a lot of information about using Google Spreadsheets but my team is more familiar with Excel

I'd like them to be able to pivot data from google analytics/create graphs and i'd like to be able to create graphs which refresh when the data refreshes

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert a Google Spreadsheet to Excel format by downloading it as "xlsx".

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing pretty much the same.

First of all, you need to have 2 separate sheets, 1 for your core data and one for your visual part (ur graphs).

In raw data sheet, get insert the data from GA
In graphs sheet, create ur graphs using the raw data.

Now, if you import new data and replace the old one, it should automatically update your graphs as well (unless you deleted some references).

In general, this could be automated, but typically you need additional tool to so so. I hope this helps